# How do I remove multiple rows in Excel using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

With this snippet of code, I'm only able to delete a single row in excel. Please suggest a solution to delete multiple rows within the same excel file.

```
public static void removeRow(HSSFSheet sheet, int rowIndex) {
        int lastRowNum=sheet.getLastRowNum();
        if(rowIndex>=0&&rowIndex<lastRowNum){
            sheet.shiftRows(rowIndex+1,lastRowNum, -1);
        }
        if(rowIndex==lastRowNum){
            HSSFRow removingRow=sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
            if(removingRow!=null){
                sheet.removeRow(removingRow);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to shift rows or actually just delete them?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I want to just delete all the rows. Also I found this code snippet from another thread, so I'm not entirely sure why the shiftRows() is being used there.

Comment: `shiftRows` moves content upwards. `removeRow` only deletes content of a row

Comment: @XtremeBaumer ok, got it. But how do I delete the content of all rows at once?

Comment: Remove sheet and then recreate. Is the fastest. `wb.removeSheetAt(wb.getSheetIndex(sheet)); wb.createSheet();`

Comment: Also, consider the deleted sheet's name while recreating a new sheet.